# Xcode 7.1 "Couldn't Load Project" after Syncing to GitHub

Tags: xcode, github

First I wasn't able to get anything on the Utilities tab on the far top left for the Identity Inspector, Size Inspector, etc.

When I tap on viewController I can't access anything. I can't navigate through the project either. Has this happened to anyone? I haven't changed the location of the project. However, I have synced the project to Github from my desktop. I'm using OS X El Capitan. This has happened for 2 projects...  This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what it looks like when I click the error:

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project file has broken. Open up your project's root directory using SourceTree. You will see all the conflicting files.

Cntrl click on the project file and launch the external merge tool.

This should open FileMerge by default. You can scroll through the file to reveal the conflicts. The tool is a bit buggy and you might have to first scroll through all the text before the red markers are revealed in the right gutter.

On each of the red marked conflicts, select the highlighted section and choose the correct code. On the top of each section, it will say which repo is which, local vs remote.

At the bottom of the FileMerge app there is an option for resolving the selected conflict. Left, Right, Left then Right, etc. Once you have fixed all the conflicts, cmd + s to save it, then cmd + q to quit it. SourceTree should then show that the file is no longer conlficting.

If you then open Xcode you will get your file tree back, where you can then fix the remaining conflicts in Xcode or using the previous technique in SourceTree.

This situation should highlight another issue, you are doing something incorrectly with git. Maybe force pushing without pulling from the remote.

commit, pull, possibly fix conflicts, push.

Comment: Do I need to be on Xcode already to open the project? How do I launch the external merge tool? I've ctrl - clicked on the file and didn't see that option. Why is it broken after syncing to GitHub?

Comment: Did you install SourceTree? Once installed, you need to choose the add existing project/workspace option. Choose your project directory. Then SourceTree will interface with git and you will see your conflicting files. Xcode can be closed during the process. In SourceTree you can cntrl click on a file marked as conflicting, they will be in the bottom pane and marked with !  What do you mean 'sync'? Which git command did you use? Or which tool?

Comment: Source tree isn't allowing me to edit the file/update the code. I see where it's conflicting, but I can't do anything about it... I've tried just clicking around everywhere, and the only thing it lets me do it remove it. Pretty awful UI.

Comment: As mentioned, cntrl click on the file and choose to launch external merge tool. That tool will show you the conflicts. The highlighted sections can be selected by clicking them, and then choosing the option you want from the dropdown on the left. This is a pretty standard thing to do when working in teams, so I would advise getting used to it.

Comment: Expiring an issue actually: http://postimg.org/image/pes4j8v8j/ + http://postimg.org/image/7dmhnqqbl/

Comment: Did you solve it? That screenshot is for the userstate xml file. It has no conflicts.